# Can anyone help me understand the notation of binary operator in the definition

Tags: functions

The definition goes,

> Let $S$ be a non-empty set. Then a function $f : S \times S \to S$ is
>   a binary operator.

If I understand correctly, then it means $(a,b) \in S \times S \Rightarrow f(a,b)=a\text{*}b  \in S$ then $\text{*}$ is a binary operator. Alright fine. But that doesn't explain that why is $f$ a binary operator?

Let me explain my doubt more clearly, I'm having trouble with notations here,

If $f(a,b) = a \text{*} b$ where $\text{*}$ is a binary operator. And if I say that $f$ is the same binary operator as well, then $f= \text{*}$.
So I can write $f(a,b)= afb$ which seems to be absurd because $b$ is not the image of $a$ under $f$. The correct expression (according to me) should be $(a,b)f(a\text{*}b)$

So, $f$ can't be $\text{*}$. I don't understand how can a relation (function in this case) be equal to a binary operator

EDIT: What I'm trying to say is,

If $R$ is a relation, then if $b$ is the image of $a$ under $R$, then we write it as, $aRb$

By the definition in my textbook, $ * : S \times S \to S $ where $*$ is a binary operator $\Rightarrow$ function $\Rightarrow$ Relation.

Then $* (a,b) = a *b $ but this would be read as $b$ is image of $a$ under $*$. This notation seems to be used widely but somehow this doesn't feel correct.

Comment: I hope I'm making myself clear.

Answer (score 2):

$*$ and $f$ are just different notations for the same underlying function. So

$a*b=c$

$f(a,b)=c$

$(a,b) \xrightarrow{f} c$

all have the same meaning. A binary operator simply maps each ordered pair of elements from $S$ (i.e. each member of $S \times S$) to an element of $S$.

Comment: If $R$ is a relation, then if $b$ is the image of $a$ under $R$, then we write it as, $aRb$ and now by the definition in my textbook, $ * : S \times S \to S $ where $*$ is a binary operator $\Rightarrow$ function $\Rightarrow$ Relation. Then $* (a,b) = a *b $ but this would be read as $b$ is image of $a$ under $*$. This notation seems to be used widely but somehow this doesn't feel correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is called binary, because $f$ has two arguments. It acts on $2$-tuples.

> So I can write $f(a,b)= afb$ which seems to be absurd because $b$ is
>   not the image of $a$ under $f$.

$a f b$ is called [infix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation). ($f a b$ is called prefix notation and $a b f$ postfix notation). All mean $f(a, b)$.

As usual, the interpretation of how you parse a given term depends on your context.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is better to use the viewpoint that some definitions can be relaxed, in some sense, and that notation changes depending on *how* we want to use an object.

Say that $\ast$ is a binary operator. Then we can take two elements, say $a, b \in S$, and combine them using $\ast$ to get $a\ast b\in S$. So a *binary operator* is something that takes two elements and combines them to give one.

Now define $f\colon S\times S \to S,\enspace f(x, y) = x\ast y$. Then $f$ takes two elements and combines them to give one, and hence $f$ is a binary operator by using the binary operation $\ast$, but we will use the notation $f(x, y)$ instead of $x\ast y$ to emphasise that we're using some function $f$, rather than *just* the binary operation $\ast$.

This is like being able to write $f(a) = b$ and $a \stackrel{f}{\mapsto} b$ interchangeably. Sometimes it's better to write the former, and sometimes it's better to write the latter, but they both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you write $afb$ then you seem to confuse the infix notation of a relation (of which a function is a special kind) and the infix notation of a binary operator (like $+$).

What the definition tries to say is that a binary operator on a set $S$ is a function $S \times S \to S.$ It doesn't however say anything about notation. But as you know, we seldom write $+(3,5) = 8,$ but instead $3+5 = 8.$ That does *not* mean that $+$ relate $3$ and $5$ like $3 < 5$ does.

If you want to use the infix notation of the function $+$ as a relation, then the correct way to write it is $(3,5)+8.$ But that's a really confusing way to write the identity that is normally written $3+5=8.$